# Is it possible to use getStaticProps and getStaticPath in a page component where you use dynamic routing but you don't know the id's yet

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

So basically I have a fully SSG app where i can not reach the backend in build time, and every data are permission and user specific, therefore i can not specify the paths in the getStaticPath method which i must use in a dynamic routed component if i want to use getStaticProps. I tried to use fallback 'blocking'  but resulted in the error : Pages with `fallback` enabled in `getStaticPaths` can not be exported. I really want to use getStaticProps on that page so i could improve on the performance.

Comment: The `fallback` property is not supported by `next export`: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features. You have two options if you can't get the data at build time: 1) Fetch the data on the client-side rather than using `getStaticProps`; 2) Do not use `next export`, use `next start` instead.

Comment: Yes i figured it out meanwhile, you are totally right thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per you situation you need to use getServerSideprops and for performance optimization you can just use some kind of caching on server-side api calls like you can use react query and hydrate it with frontend this will boost your performance.

[React query docs with next js SSR](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/ssr)

Answer (score 0):

> where i can not reach the backend in build time, and every data are **permission and user specific**,

You are describing `getServerSideProps`, your site is not an SSG.

Comment: I don't want to compute the data for every request since it is fully static and the frontend side does not running a frontend server only using the exported static files.

Comment: @MárkWerner I think I see what you are saying. You do not need to use a data fetching method at all. Just make an "app shell" style page that is static rendered as much as possible, but have it fetch user specific API data in `useEffect` or `componentDidMount` and render it entirely client side. They do this a lot in Gatsby where there *is no server at all*